# Get the Javax Validation Annotation Attribute Value

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, annotations

I have set of properties with typical Java validation annotations (Hibernate implementation), e.g.,

```
@Size(max = 10)
private String data;
```

I would like to know if programmatically the `Size's max` value can be accessed.

This is needed to perform some transformative operation on `data` when it's retrieved. Obviously, `10` can be hard coded to a final static class variable, but is there a way to access these annotation values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the annotation has a runtime retention, you can access it through reflection. For instance (ignoring any exceptions):

```
Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("data");
Size size = field.getAnnotation(Field.class);
int max = size.max();
```

If you want to get the value that triggered a constraint error, catch the `ConstraintViolationException`. You can then get the constraint annotation from the violation. Another example:

```
// just some code to get a descriptor
ConstraintDescriptor<?> descriptor = constraintViolationException.getAnnotations().stream()
        .map(ConstraintViolation::getConstraintDescriptor)
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow();

// now its properties can be accessed
Map<String, Object> attributes = descriptor.getAttributes();
// attributes contains an entry with key "max" and value 10 for your @Size annotation
Size size = (Size) descriptor.getAnnotation();
int max = size.max();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```java
public class YourAnnotationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<YourAnnotation, String> {

  private Integer yourAnnotationProperty ;


  @Override
  public void initialize(YourAnnotation constraintAnnotation) {
    yourAnnotationProperty = constraintAnnotation.values();
  }

  public boolean isValid(String yourClassPropertyValue, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
     // your logic code using the property
     return true;
  }
}
```